# Order collection of array objects

Tags: arrays, laravel, collections, eloquent, laravel-5.1

After making some queryes i have a collection of array objects. But after orderByDesc the data transform in hole objects, instead of how it was (array of objects), what it happened? Is like the method orderByDesc tranform the collection in another type.

Ex:
some logic code, queries...etc
in the end

```
return $total->sortByDesc('date');
```

After using sortByDesc:

[image]

Before to sortByDesc:
[image]

Now that is in type of objects is giving some issues working with it in my javascript application (angularjs), it not a array of objects how should it be.

Comment: try `return $total->sortByDesc('date')->toArray();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to copy the collection when sorting and use `values()`

```
$sorted = $total->sortByDesc('date');
dd($sorted->values());
```

Same result?

Comment: When you do collection manipulation, it changes the values. That's why you copy to  a new variable, and take the variables values(). Don't forget to upvote and mark my answer. Thanks :)